# How do I return default value for sales force custom object boolean field, in apex?

Tags: salesforce, field, default, default-value

I am trying to return the default value for a field of type boolean, which belongs to a salesforce custom object.

Once I have my field, I'm using:

```
sObjectField.getDescribe().getDefaultValue()
```

But it always returns null for a boolean field!

I'm returning default picklist values in the following manner:

```
for(Schema.PicklistEntry picklistEntry : sObjectField.getDescribe().getPicklistValues()) {
  if(picklistEntry.isDefaultValue()) {
    defaultValue = picklistEntry.getValue();
  }
}
```

I can get the defualt value for a telephone number field by using:

```
sObjectField.getDescribe().getDefaultValueFormula();
```

Why can't I get the default value for a Boolean?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality appears to be broken in Salesforce / APEX. I ran this code in execute anonymous to return all possible getDescribe attributes & values for a field:

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult DFR = account.checkboxfield__c.getDescribe();
System.debug( DFR );
```

What I found is that none of the attributes correctly return the default value on a Boolean field (checkbox in SF terms). I ran just a getDescribe() so that I could see all possible attributes in the case where a new one was added to solve for this particular issue, but it turns out only getDefaultValue() and or getDefaultValueFormula() can return a field's default value.  I tested this with multiple fields types and verified that the [official documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm) does not state some type of exclusion for returning the default value on checkboxes. If I am not mistaken, you may have found a bug in APEX. If I were you I would go to the Salesforce support site and search for any official documentation around the issue being found. If you can't find evidence that the issue has been documented, open a ticket with Salesforce and have them test / document the issue.

If this turns out to not be a bug, then at a minimum Salesforce needs to update their [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm) to describe how to return this value since getDefaultValue() and getDefaultValueFormula() don't work.